# Group array by nested array id

Tags: javascript

I have object that consists of arrays that have id of array thay should be in group with. For example arr0 should be in one group with arr2 [arr0,arr2]

```
{
 arr0:[0,2]
 arr1:[1,4]
 arr2:[0,2,4]
 arr3:[3]
 arr4:[1,2,4]
}
```

after i should have grouped object, or array.. can anyone help with logic?

```
"0" = {
 arr0:[0,2]
 arr1:[1,4]
 arr2:[0,2,4]
 arr4:[1,2,4]
}
"1" ={
 arr3:[3]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the criteria you're using to group the arrays.

Comment: @JoeClay `[0,2]` means `arr0` and `arr2`

Comment: @JoeClay I have added an answer based on my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

- Create an array to visited nodes.
- Now loop over data and check if node is visited, skip, else go to child and get entire tree.
- In tree, keep recursively creating nodes and skip any node that has been visited in current branch.

```js
var data = { arr0: [0, 2], arr1: [1, 4], arr2: [0, 2, 4], arr3: [3], arr4: [1, 2, 4], }

var r = {};
var prefix = "arr"
var visitedNodes = [];
for (var k in data) {
  // This will hold the group
  var obj = {};
  
  // This is the index value of first parent in recursion
  var v = +k.replace(prefix, '');
  
  // Check if a node is visited using some other node
  if (visitedNodes.indexOf(v) === -1)
    getChild(k, v, obj);
  
  // If object is updated in loop, update in final object
  if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0)
    r[v] = obj;
}
console.log(r)

function getChild(key, pos, result) {
  data[key].forEach(function(k, i) {
    var o = prefix + k;
    // Check if current index is same as first parent. If yes, just push and stop loop.
    // This will prevent infinite recursion
    if (pos === k && !result[o]) {
      result[o] = data[o];
      visitedNodes.push(k);
      return
    }
    
    // Check if in current tree chain, current node is not visited
    if (!result[o]) {
      visitedNodes.push(k)
      result[o] = data[o];
      getChild((o), pos, result)
    }
  })
}
```